# htaccess if folder exists check folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am learning htaccess files at this moment and ive come across an issue I cannot seem to solve.

At this moment im using this htacces to make a clean url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-A-Z]+)/([0-9a-z-A-Z]+) ?menu=$1&page=$2.php [NC,L]
```

I have 2 possible file locations:

1. `/menu/page`
2. `/menu/Controller/Page`

I want both of them to just show: `/menu/page` in the URL

So I did that. It shows what I want in the url. But becouse im referring in my menu to the second as `/menu/Controller/Page` I get this error:

> Warning: include(Partials/Programmeren/Opdracht1Restwaarde.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 20.

This is my index page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_GET['page']) ){
    //Heres a problem I know this. I only dont know how to fix it.
    $cPagina = $_GET['menu'] . '/' .$_GET['page'];
} elseif( isset($_SESSION['laatstGebruiktePagina']) ) {
    $cPagina = $_SESSION['laatstGebruiktePagina'];
} else {
    $cPagina = 'indexcontent.php';
}
$_SESSION['laatstGebruiktePagina'] = $cPagina;

include "Partials/head.php";
include "Partials/navbar.php";

//problem include:
include("Partials/$cPagina");
?>
```

So at the point in the above php code I have a place where I specify the location of the file. but sometime it should be: `$cPagina = $_GET['menu'] . '/controller/' .$_GET['page'];`. At first I thought i could simply do this with a if statement. but I cant becouse there is nothing to check it with.

ADDITION: Im not necessarily asking for some code that fixes this for me. Even a point in the right direction on where I can read this or something is appreciated. Im reading about htaccess at the apache site and some other tutorials at this moment

Comment: Bit unclear. What is URL shown in browser and what it should be rewritten to for both cases?

Comment: Ill add it in question sorry if I am unclear

Comment: @anubhava Ive added it i guess and got the question a bit more detailed on point.

Comment: _“I have 2 possible file locations”_ - why, and what’s the logic behind that? If both existed, which one should get preference? _“At first I thought i could simply do this with a if statement. but I cant becouse there is nothing to check it with”_ - the existence of a specific file in the server file system is what you want to check, no? How is that “nothing to check with”?

Comment: @CBroe Im sure there is a way to "check" if the folder exists. but as i said im just starting to learn the htaccess thats why I asked. To find out these things are possible and as anubhava showed in his answer it is actually possible so now i can try to create this myself. and the logic behind it (I thought this was logic) is that i have menu items that are just buttons and menu items with sub menu items that are in an deeper layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ ?menu=$1&page=$2.php [NC,L]
```

This will take care of both these cases:

```
/menu/page
/menu/Controller/Page
```

and forward those to:

```
?menu=menu&page=page.php
?menu=menu/Controller&page=page.php
```

respectively so that you can continue to use:

```
$cPagina = $_GET['menu'] . '/' .$_GET['page'];
```

in your code.

Comment: Hmm this does actually go in the right direction only its referring to the wrong folder. there are 3 folders, `controller`, `model`, `view` and it tries to find the page in `view`, so it still crashes out but at least its looking a layer deeper so ill fiddle arround with it i guess

Comment: There is 1 rules before this its for the home button that is in the topmost layer. `RewriteRule ^home ?page=indexcontent.php [NC,L]`

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem content etc is loaded again. but in the url it now shows `menu/controller/page` is there a way to not break this completelly again and just show `menu/page` ?

Comment: So you want to show `/menu/page` in browser but still load php file as `/menu/controller/page.php` ?

Comment: Yes. thats exactly what i want to do. but i guess the whole code breaks then? at least if i understand correctly

Comment: It needs to parse `/menu/controller/page.php` to the php file for the include and in the url i only want to show `/menu/page`. but then the problem that there is the other structure that only needs to parse `/menu/page` for the include. so if i fix the first problem the other breaks. and the same for the other way arround

Comment: Yes that's correct. If URL is `/menu/page` then there is no way php code would know where the `.php` file is since it can be `/menu/Controller/page.php` or `/menu/someFolder/page.php`. It is better to keep different URL for different folders.

Comment: Ok i will  keep the current setup then, really thanks for the help i learned quite a lot from this :) !